# jQuery refresh DOM after adding elements to HTML

Tags: jquery, dom

I did find many similar questions but none with the solution that could help me solve my problem.

I am inserting HTML elements to my page and later on I want to count them. since the newly created elements are not part of DOM so count returns `0`.

Code:

```
$('#addSlide').on('click', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
    reader.onloadend = function(){
       slideImg = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
       // ADDING ELEMENTS
       var slide = '<div class="slide"><img src="'+slideImg +'" /></div>';
       $('#Container').append(slide);
    };
    // EXECUTING SOME FUNCTION
    somename();
});

function somename(){
    var slideCount = '';
    slideCount = $('#Container div').length;
    console.log(slideCount);
    // ALWAYS RETURNS '0' REGARDLESS TO HOW MANY SLIDES ARE ADDED
    if( slideCount > 1 ) {
       // SOME CODE ...
    }
}
```

How can I refresh the DOM so that I can use the newly created elements in my code?

Comment: In this case it's probably just that you're calling count() before your FileReader is complete.  Move the somename() call to inside the onloadend block (after the .append line) so that it's not called until the load is complete.

Comment: @Daniel friend even when `somename()` is called in `reader.onloadend` ? where else should I call it then?

Comment: @Daniel you are right, i added the `somename()` within `reader.onloadend` and it works now. please post as an answer so i can mark it.

Comment: Easy enough to get a line out of order, and hard to spot in your own code!  Answer is posted, and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your updated code, you are just calling the count function in the wrong place.

```
$('#addSlide').on('click', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
    reader.onloadend = function(){
       slideImg = URL.createObjectURL(inputFile);
       // ADDING ELEMENTS
       var slide = '<div class="slide"><img src="'+slideImg +'" /></div>';
       $('#Container').append(slide);
       // CALL IT HERE 
       somename()
    };
    // EXECUTING SOME FUNCTION
    // NOT HERE somename();
});
```

Otherwise you call your count function before the asynchronous FileReader is complete.

Comment: Thanks Friend for all your help. I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

It works just the way you have it are you sure you are adding the divs before you check the count the code you have functions as it should ex:

```js
var slide = '<div class="slide">asdfasdf</div>';
$('#Container').append(slide);
$('#Container').append(slide);
somename();
function somename() {

  var slideCount = '';
  slideCount = $('#Container div').length;
  console.log(slideCount);
  // ALWAYS RETURNS '0' REGARDLESS TO HOW MANY SLIDES ARE ADDED

  if (slideCount > 1) {
    // SOME CODE ...
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container"></div>
```

Comment: I am adding images via filereader, maybe this is the reason. I updated my codes with more info so you friends can guide me